# Why does the time not update live in my vue.js component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Right now I have my component working where it will show the duration when given a `time_start` and `time_end`, but I am trying to show the live duration if no `time_end` is given.  All of this logic happens inside of calculateDuration method, but I had to create another wrapper method `liveDuration` to keep updating the calculateDuration every second.  With the code below, I am seeing errors appear in the console every second

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

but if i click on the error in the console, it shows me the correct duration

```
0 hrs 1 min 7 sec
```

However, all that's rendered in the template is a static number such as 5 or 7 which never updates, and I'm not sure where these numbers are coming from.

How do I update the code below so that the duration is live updated every second in the template?

```
<template>
  <div class="executions">
    <h3>Recent Jobs</h3>
    <table>
      <template>
        <tr>
          <td><b>Job</b></td>
          <td><b>Duration</b></td>
          <td><b>Result</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
          <td>
          <template v-if="item.duration == 'N/A'">
            {{ liveUpdate(item.time_start) }}
          </template>
          <template v-else>
            {{ item.duration }}
          </template>
          </td>
          <td>{{ item.status }}</td>
        </tr>
      </template>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import moment from "moment";

export default {
  name: "Executions",
  data() {
    return {
      job_execs: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    calculateDuration: function(time_start, time_end) {
      let duration = "N/A"
      if (time_start && time_end) {
        time_start = moment(time_start)
        time_end = moment(time_end)
        duration = moment.duration(time_end.diff(time_start));
        if (duration.seconds() == 0) {
          duration = "N/A";
        } else {
          duration =
          duration.hours() +
          " hrs " +
          duration.minutes() +
          " min " +
          duration.seconds() +
          " sec";
        }
        time_start = time_start.format("LLL")
        time_end = time_end.format("LLL")
      }
      if (time_start == null) {
        time_start = "N/A";
      }
      else {
        time_start = moment(time_start).format("LLL")
      }
      if (time_end == null) {
        time_end = "N/A";
      }
      else {
        time_end = moment(time_end).format("LLL")
      }
      return {time_start, time_end, duration}
    },
    liveDuration: function(time_start) {
      let now = moment();
      let duration = "N/A"
      console.log(time_start)
      if (time_start) {
        console.log(time_start)
        time_start = moment(time_start)
        console.log(time_start)
        let time_current = moment()
        console.log(time_current)
        duration = moment.duration(time_current.diff(time_start));
        console.log(duration)
        if (duration.seconds() == 0) {
          duration = "N/A";
        } else {
          duration =
          duration.hours() +
          " hrs " +
          duration.minutes() +
          " min " +
          duration.seconds() +
          " sec";
        }
      }
      return duration
    },
    liveUpdate: function(time_start) {
      let that=this;
      let time_live = setInterval(that.liveDuration(time_start), 1000);
      return time_live
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.jobExecEndpoint = 'http://test'
    fetch(this.jobExecEndpoint)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(body => {
        for (let i = 0; i < body.length; i++) {
          let {time_start, time_end, duration} = this.calculateDuration(body[i].time_start, body[i].time_end);
          this.job_execs.push({
            id: body[i].id,
            time_start: time_start,
            time_end: time_end,
            duration: duration,
            status: body[i].status.name,
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Error Fetching:", this.jobExecEndpoint, err);
        return { failure: this.jobExecEndpoint, reason: err };
      });
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: all the data being pushed into job_execs is valid and tested and being used elsewhere within this application so i know that is not the issue

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is with the value that the liveUpdate method returns. It returns a setInterval handler and that is not the duration that you want to show.
Second problem is that even if the method returns the correct value it won't get updated automatically. If you want it to update for example each 1 second, you should use setInterval in the mounted hook and update the data in each interval. Updating the data will automatically and reactively update the view.

Comment: Do you have an example?  I'm not sure how I would accomplish this I have a few questions.  One thing I'm not sure how it would work is if I'm already pushing data into job_execs in the created hook, how would i then update the duration for each object in job_execs from mounted?

Comment: I think you can in each time interval iterate over the job_execs array and if duration is not defined for an item, calculate the liveDuration for that item. Then put that duration data in the item (e.g. item[liveDuration] = liveDuration). Then you can show that value in your template if duration is not defined and it will get updated in each interval.